# Create table with ellipsis in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, ellipsis

I would like to show the top and bottom values in a table using kable.  Ideally I would like to do this with an ellipsis (...) in between.  Is there a way to combine two tables in such a manner in RMarkdown?

Ideal output would be:

```
Fruit       Power Ranking
-----------------------
Watermelon       1
Strawberry       2
Açai             3
      ........
Tomato           98
Grapefruit       99
Lemon            100
```

Comment: It is a bit of a hack but how about a data frame `elips` with "...", then `rbind(head(df), elips, tail(df))`

Comment: This worked perfect actually. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With a reproducible example:

```
dt <- data.table::data.table(
  Fruit = letters, 
  Ranking = seq_along(letters)
)

print(dt, topn = 3)

    Fruit Ranking
 1:     a       1
 2:     b       2
 3:     c       3
---              
24:     x      24
25:     y      25
26:     z      26
```